# Multipart upload performance issues to Digital Ocean Spaces from browsers on Windows

Tags: digital-ocean, object-storage, digital-ocean-spaces, multipart-upload

I've run into a really strange issue with uploads to Digital Ocean Spaces.

We'd been getting more and more complaints from users (starting beginning of November) that uploads were really slow. We couldn't reproduce any performance issues on our machines (Mac) but couldn't really ignore the complaints so I began to dig a little deeper.

**What we've determined so far**

- Performance is 10-20x slower if the following criteria are met:

  - On Windows (we've tested with Firefox, Chrome, Edge). MacOS is fine.
  - Multipart upload `PUT` (with presigned url, but single file `PUT` is fine)
  - AMS3 region (all buckets there are slow, but we tested FRA1 which is fine)
- A 15MB single file upload will complete in  under 3 seconds. A 15MB part of a multipart will also complete in under 3 seconds on Mac. On Windows under the conditions above: 25-45 seconds or even longer.
- In browsers only, command line api is fine. (Main difference is presigned urls?)
- It started around the beginning of November, where we see an extreme drop in overall multipart upload speed from Windows.
- ISP doesn't matter (we tested several)

We use Uppy for multipart uploads with an API providing the signed `PUT` urls.
To rule out *any* issues with the code we've even written a quick proof-of-concept without uppy to do the upload, and it was still slow.

Does anyone have *any* idea what could be happening here? Can anyone reproduce this problem on their AMS3 space on Windows?

I'm currenlty in contact with DO support of course, but they take ages to respond and have not been helpful so far. I do suspect it's something on their end but it's just so *weird* and any push in right direction might also help them solve this faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue has not been resolved. Digital Ocean have been very unhelpful to say the least. The solution for now seems to be to create a _new_ bucket in the AMS3 region (it seems that only existing buckets are affected) and clone all data to this new bucket.
However, the rclone command and the corresponding Digital Ocean documentation do not work (unsupported operation) and we are waiting for a reply on how to make it work.